# Coding site with test harness for basic data structures like linked list,graph,strings etc

Tags: c, linked-list

Are there any coding sites with test harness for basic data structures and with basic problems like arrays,strings,linked list,graph adjacency list etc, so that I can brush up on basic codes like reversing linked list, checking if linked list is palindrome, sorting linked list, finding a substring in a string etc. This would make basic DS brushing fun.

I know there are sites like codechef and topcoder, but from what I have seen, these don't have such basic list,graph conceptual DS questions and test harness.

And, it can also be perhaps used for undergrad course in DS..

Comment: +1 there seems to be a major lack of free, publicly available test harness packages of any sort, and it's nice to see a question that might turn up some.